# Why the following snippet doesn't work in JS?

Tags: javascript, scope

Following is the code:

```
var myVar = {
    test:function(){
       alert('hello');        
    },
    myinternalObj: {
        internalTest: myVar.test
    }
};
```

Why in javascript I'm unable to assign myVar.test to internalTest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myVar.test` is evaluated **before** the assignment (of the object literal) to `myVar` and thus `myVar` is undefined and accessing a property on `undefined` or `null` results in an error.

Answer (score 1):

At the line `internalTest: myVar.test`, myVar has not been defined yet (you are still defining it with the property `internalTest`.

You need to change to code to

```
var myVar = {
    test:function(){
       alert('hello');        
    }
};
myVar.myinternalObj = {
    internalTest: myVar.test
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When the engine reads myVar.test it does not yet have a value

Answer (score 0):

`myVar` is not known inside its own definition, you shoud write:

```
var myVar = {
    test:function(){
       alert('hello');        
    }
};
myVar.myinternalObj = { internalTest : myVar.test };
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the object you are referencing in myinternalObj is not initialized yet.

A simpler version looks like

```
var object = {a:'a', b: object.a};
```

The initialization of the object is not finished when you reference it inside itself.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because when myinternalObj is set, myVar is still being set.

What exactly are you trying to achieve. I suppose your code could be refactored.

Answer (score 0):

The following works in a JS console:

```
> var myVar = {}
undefined

> myVar.test = function() { alert('hello'); }
function () { alert('hello'); }

> myVar.myinternalObj = { internalTest: myVar.test }
Object

> myVar.myinternalObj.internalTest();
//shows the alert
```